# React Native | How to render Markers after click on Button ( onPress() )

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-maps

I want to build an App that is similiar to Uber. The thing is in the react-native-maps documentation it only provide how to render  directly

In my case i want the `<Marker/>` to be rendered after onPress() ( clicked a button ) How to achieve this?

I have tried to change the state which the `<Marker/>` component inside the `<MapView>` used but it seems like it's not re-rendered

Constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            updatesEnabled: false,
            location: {},
            modalCategoryVisible: false,
            markers: []
        }
    }
```

onPress handle:

```
_searchStreetVendors = () => {
        this.setState({
            markers: [
                {
                    merchant_name: "Zaky",
                    merchant_type: "Sate",
                    merchant_info: "Selling Sate that is tasty",
                    merchant_phone: "0812909281234",
                    location: {
                        latitude: -6.667772,
                        longitude: 106.723630,
                    }
                },
            ]
        })
    }
```

MapView:

```
render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    ref={(mapView) => { _mapView = mapView; }}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: -6.174969,
                        longitude: 106.827202,
                        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                    }}>
                    {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                        <MapViewMarker
                            coordinate={marker.location}
                            title={marker.title}
                            description={marker.description}
                        />
                    ))}
                </MapView>
                ...
             <View/>
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not re-rendered? It'll only render once because `state.markers` only has one value in it.

Comment: @Dan i thought that it should be re-rendered if a state was changed?

Comment: Your marker will never change because you are setting `state.markers` to the same value every time you call `_searchStreetVendors`. You're right, when state changes, it does cause a re-render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two small changes in your code and it's rendering marker for me

```
_searchStreetVendors = () => {
    this.setState({
        markers: [
            {
                merchant_name: "Zaky",
                merchant_type: "Sate",
                merchant_info: "Selling Sate that is tasty",
                merchant_phone: "0812909281234",
                key: 1,
                location: {
                    latitude: -6.174969,
                    longitude: 106.827202,
                }
            },
        ]
    })
}

<MapView
    style={styles.map}
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    ref={(mapView) => { _mapView = mapView; }}
    initialRegion={{
        latitude: -6.174969,
        longitude: 106.827202,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    }}>
    {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
        <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={marker.location}
            title={marker.title}
            description={marker.description}
            key={marker.key}
        />
    ))}
</MapView>
```

1) Added Key, which needed when you render multple marker on the screen, which was shown as a warning

2) **MapView.Maker**, I found there was no dot between the text which was giving me an error

Also changed marker location same as initialRegion just to check the marker is rendering or not, So check once and let me know if you're still getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

And change the parameters in the map functions, you are using keys that are not in the location dictionary.(marker.title and marker.description are not in the dictionary )

```
renderMarkers() {
    return this.state.markers.map((marker) => {
      return (
        <MapViewMarker
            coordinate={marker.location}
            title={marker.merchant_name}
            description={marker. merchant_info}
        />
      )
    })
}

render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                    style={styles.map}
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    ref={(mapView) => { _mapView = mapView; }}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: -6.174969,
                        longitude: 106.827202,
                        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                    }}>
                    {this.state.markers.length > 0 ? this.renderMarkers() : null}
                </MapView>
                ...
             <View/>
}
```